# How to pass complex DevOps pipeline template parameter to script

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In an Azure DevOps pipeline template, I am declaring a parameter as an array/sequence

```
parameters:
  mySubscription: ''
  myArray: []

steps:
- AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.mySubscription }}
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/script.ps1
    arguments: '-MyYAMLArgument ${{ parameters.myArray }}'
```

Value for the parameter is then passed from pipeline definition as

```
steps:
- template: myTemplate.yml
  parameters:
    mySubscription: 'azure-connection'
    myArray:
    - field1: 'a'
      field2: 'b'
    - field1: 'aa'
      field2: 'bb'
```

My problem is I can't pass that array as-is in YAML syntax (kind of `ToString()`) to be able to consume and treat that array from PowerShell in my template. When trying to run this pipeline, I get the following error:
`/myTemplate.yml (Line: X, Col: X): Unable to convert from Array to String. Value: Array`. The line/column referenced in the error message correspond to `arguments: '-MyYAMLArgument ${{ parameters.myArray }}'` from my template.

I also tried to map the parameter as an environment for my script

```
- AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.mySubscription }}
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/script.ps1
    arguments: '-MyYAMLArgument $Env:MY_ENV_VAR'
  env:
    MY_ENV_VAR: ${{ parameters.myArray }}
```

This does not work too: 
`/myTemplate.yml (Line: X, Col: Y): A sequence was not expected`. That time line/column refers to `MY_ENV_VAR: ${{ parameters.myArray }}`.

Does anyone ever faced a similar requirement to pass complex types (here an array/sequence of object) defined from the pipeline definition to a PowerShell script? If so, how did you achieve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can now convert these types of parameters to String using the  `convertToJson` function in an ADO pipeline:

```
parameters:
  - name: myParameter
    type: object
    default:
        name1: value1
        name2: value2

...

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      echo "${{ convertToJson(parameters.myParameter) }}"
```

ref: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-type-casting-or-expression-function-from-yam/880210

convertToJson: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#converttojson

Comment: This is great! I did run into an issue if you attempt to pass this as a parameter to a PowerShell script as an argument where the entire string was not coming through.  The workaround was to set it as an environment variable to the script instead.

Comment: We have to be careful using undocumented functions - Hopefully this will become mainstream, but it could just as easily vanish overnight!

Comment: One approach might be to replace `Bash@3` wth `PythonScript@0` and use the json library to cleanly unpack the parameters into python variables.

Comment: Thanks! it didn't work to me as is for Powershell - seems that convertToJson adds new lines which Powershell script doesn't like. See in my answer how I solved it with ConvertFrom-Json Powershell function. BTW convertToJson is already documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Comment: Edited now that convertToJson is now mainstream+documented -thanks @MaMazav

Comment: unfortunately convertToJson does not know of possible ##vso[] commands. I use replace(input, search, replaceWith) for that. From the same link as in this answer.
So when you have jobs parameter/var with script task inline command having a vso command, it can get rendered if you log it and then getting parsed as a real vso command... oops. But that is not in the question though, just want to mention it.

Answer (score 11):

Based on convertToJson idea by @ed-randall, together with ConvertFrom-Json Powershell function, we can use a JSON 'contract' to pass values between yaml and PS script:

```
- powershell: |
    $myArray = '${{ convertToJson(parameters.myArray) }}' | ConvertFrom-Json
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm facing a similar problem. My workaround is to flatten the array into a string using different separators for different dimensions.

For example I want to make some parameters required and fail the build if these parameters are not passed. Instead of adding a task for every parameter to check, I want to do this in a single task.

To do this, I first pass, as a parameter (to another template, called `check-required-params.yml` which holds the task responsible for checking the parameters), an array where each element is a string of the type `name:value` which is a concatenation (using the `format` expression) of the `name` and the `value` of required parameters separated by a colon:

```yaml
# templates/pipeline-template.yml
parameters:
- name: endpoint
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: rootDirectory
  type: string
  default: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
- name: remoteDirectory
  type: string
  default: '/'
- name: archiveName
  type: string
  default: ''
    
#other stuff

      - template: check-required-params.yml
        parameters:
          requiredParams:
          - ${{ format('endpoint:{0}', parameters.endpont) }}
          - ${{ format('archiveName:{0}', parameters.archiveName) }}
```

Then in `check-required-params.yml`, I join the array separating the elements with a semicolon using the expression `${{ join(';', parameters.requiredParams) }}`. This creates a string of the type `endpoint:value;archiveName:value` and passes this as an environmental variable.

At this point, using a little string manipulation, in a script I can split the string using the semicolon as a separator so I will get an array of strings like `name:value` which I can further split, this time using a colon as the separator. My `check-required-params.yml` looks like:

```yaml
# templates/check-required-params.yml
parameters:
- name: requiredParams
  type: object
  default: []    
        
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  env:
    REQURED_PARAMS: ${{ join(';', parameters.requiredParams) }}
  displayName: Check for required parameters
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    pwsh: true
    script: |
      $params = $env:REQURED_PARAMS -split ";"
      foreach($param in $params) {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($param.Split(":")[1])) {
          Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Missing template parameter $($param.Split(":")[0])"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]"
      }
    }
```

Then in my `azure-pipelines.yml` I can do:

```yaml
#other stuff
- template: templates/pipeline-template.yml
  parameters:
    endpoint: 'myEndpoint'
    rootDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/mycode
```

In this example, the build will fail because I don't pass the parameter `archiveName`.

You can add some flexibility by using variables to define the separators instead of hardcoding them in the scripts and in the expressions.

Comment: This is great, but this will fail if no parameters are specified because ```$env:REQUIRED_PARAMS -split ";"``` will return an array with an empty element. You can fix this with a quick check ```if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:REQUIRED_PARAMS) -eq $false)```

Answer (score 2):

## Script file arguments

The below example provides the syntax needed to pass a Azure DevOps yaml boolean and an array to a PowerShell script file via arguments.

boolean -> Switch

object -> Array

### Powershell Script

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [switch]
    $Check,

    [Parameter()]
    [string[]]
    $Array
)

If($Check.IsPresent)
{
    Write-Host "Check is present"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Check is not present"
}

Write-Host "Next we loop the array..."
Foreach($a in $Array){
    Write-Host "Item in the array: $a"
}
```

### Yaml Pipeline

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

parameters:
  - name: checkBool
    type: boolean

  - name: paramArray
    type: object
    default:
      - one
      - two

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: 'Scripts/DebugSwitches.ps1'
    arguments: -Check:$${{ parameters.checkBool }} -Array ${{ join(', ', parameters.paramArray) }}
```

### Boolean Syntax

Notice the yaml boolean is passed to the PowerShell switch parameter with a colon ':' with no spaces.

### Array Syntax

Notice the yaml object array above uses the [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#join) operator to format the array as a comma separated array that is passed to the PowerShell array argument.

Answer (score 1):

> How to pass complex DevOps pipeline template parameter to script

I am afraid we could not pass complex DevOps pipeline template parameters to a PowerShell script.

Currently, the task of Azure devops only supports the transfer of one-dimensional arrays. It cannot accept and transfer two-dimensional arrays. Although we can define the parameters of a two-dimensional array, but we need to extend the parameters from a template by the scripts like:

```
- ${{ each field in parameters.myArray}}:
```

We could use it like:

```
- ${{ each step in parameters.buildSteps }}:
  #- ${{ each pair in step }}:

    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType : inline
        script: |
          Write-Host 'Hello World'
```

But we could not pass the two-dimensional arrays directly to the task like: `[field1: 'a', field2: 'b']`. That the reason why you got the error `Unable to convert from Array to String`.

You could check document [Extend from a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Leo Liu MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7460777/leo-liu-msft) [mentioned in its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59987335/2242485), this is indeed not supported right now but someone already [opened an issue for this improvement](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/427) .

This issue also contains a good workaround for now to use environment variables instead. Draw back of this solution is you need to be aware of the data structure in order to map it properly.

```
parameters:
  mylist:[]
  #where mylist is a sequence of object matching the mapping:
  #- name: 'the name 1'
  #  value: 'the value of 1'
  #  index: 0
  #- name: 'the name 2'
  #  value: 'the value of 2'
  #  index: 1

env:
  ${{ each item in parameters.mylist }}:
    ${{ format('SCRIPT_PARAM_{0}_KEY', item.index) }}: ${{ item.name }}
    ${{ format('SCRIPT_PARAM_{0}_VAL', item.index) }}: ${{ item.value }}
```