# Azure Devops: Template use sequence typed parameter to generate jobs and stages

Tags: azure-devops

It seems the template variable does not support sequence type but the template parameter does support it(called object type in Microsoft doc), together with JobList type and StageList type, but they seem to be just sequences with defined schema.

When iterating through object-typed parameter to generate step I didn't meet any problem, but I got error called 'A sequence was not expected' when I was trying to do such to generate jobs and stages.

So the result have to be like this:

```yaml
# main.yml:
trigger: none

extends:
  template: template.yml
  parameters:
    PROJECTNAME: foo.bar
    DEPLOYMENTTARGETS:
      - stage:
        jobs:
          - deployment:
            environment:
              name: TEST
              tags: Web # tag must be comma separated string which is also kinda weird
      - stage:
        jobs:
          - deployment:
            environment:
              name: PROD
              tags: Web



# template.yml:
parameters:
  - name: PROJECTNAME
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: DEPLOYMENTTARGETS
    type: stageList # I was expecting object to be working
    default: []

variables:
  - group: LoginSecrets

stages:
  - ${{ each  deploymentTarget in parameters.DEPLOYMENTTARGETS }}: # iterating through an object here will result in error: 'A sequence was not expected', iterating through  a StageList is OK
      - stage: Deploy_${{replace(parameters.PROJECTNAME,'.','_')}}_${{replace(deploymentTarget.jobs[0].environment.name,'-','')}}_${{replace(replace(deploymentTarget.jobs[0].environment.tags,',','_'),'-','')}}_Stage # assuming each stage contains only one deployment job. We also iterate through jobs here if required.
        dependsOn: BuildAndPublish_${{replace(parameters.PROJECTNAME,'.','_')}}_Stage
        jobs:
          - deployment: Deploy_${{replace(parameters.PROJECTNAME,'.','_')}}_Job
            environment:
              name: ${{deploymentTarget.jobs[0].environment.name}}
              resourceType: VirtualMachine
              tags: ${{deploymentTarget.jobs[0].environment.tags}}
            strategy:
              runOnce:
                deploy:
                  steps:
                    - pwsh: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.PROJECTNAME}}/pipelineRelease.ps1
                      env:
                        LOGINNAME: $(loginName)
                        LOGINPASSWORD: $(loginPassword)
                        PROJECTNAME: ${{parameters.PROJECTNAME}}
```

But I was expecting something like this to be working:

```yaml
# main.yml:
trigger: none

extends:
  template: template.yml
  parameters:
    PROJECTNAME: foo.bar
    DEPLOYMENTTARGETS:
      - EnvName: TEST
        Tags: Web
      - EnvName: PROD
        Tags: Web

# template.yml:
parameters:
  - name: PROJECTNAME
    type: string
    default: ""
  - name: DEPLOYMENTTARGETS
    type: object # instead of StageList, I passed an object here
    default: []

variables:
  - group: LoginSecrets

stages:
  - ${{ each  deploymentTarget in parameters.DEPLOYMENTTARGETS }}: # error here
      - stage: Deploy_${{replace(parameters.PROJECTNAME,'.','_')}}_${{replace(deploymentTarget.EnvName,'-','')}}_${{replace(replace(deploymentTargetTags,',','_'),'-','')}}_Stage
        dependsOn: BuildAndPublish_${{replace(parameters.PROJECTNAME,'.','_')}}_Stage
        jobs:
          - deployment: Deploy_${{replace(parameters.PROJECTNAME,'.','_')}}_Job
            environment:
              name: ${{deploymentTarget.EnvName}}
              resourceType: VirtualMachine
              tags: ${{deploymentTarget.Tags}}
            strategy:
              runOnce:
                deploy:
                  steps:
                    - pwsh: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.PROJECTNAME}}/pipelineRelease.ps1
                      env:
                        LOGINNAME: $(loginName)
                        LOGINPASSWORD: $(loginPassword)
                        PROJECTNAME: ${{parameters.PROJECTNAME}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Devops: Template use sequence typed parameter to generate jobs and stages

I am afraid we have to use the `stageList` instead of `object` to transfer two-dimensional arrays.

That because the parameters is defined as two-dimensional arrays in the `main.yml`, But if we define this arrays as `object` in the `template.yml` file. In this case, we could not loop the object in the template file.

You could check the document [Loop through parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#loop-through-parameters) for some more details.

Also, you could check the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972329/how-to-pass-complex-devops-pipeline-template-parameter-to-script) for some details.

Comment: I'd like to suggest supporting sequence(array) explicitly in parameters(perhaps variables too) as a solution. It feels inconsistent when you are forced to iterate through something like StepList/JobList/StageList while they are essentially just sequences with defined schema.