# Using if else conditions within a Azure devops yaml pipeline template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Essentially I am trying to use a if else logic inside a yaml template instead of the caller pipeline.

I have following two pipelines azure-caller.yml and template.yaml

**azure-caller.yml**

```
parameters:
  - name: test
    displayName: 'select true or false' 
    values:
      - true
      - false
  

variables:
- name: test-true
  ${{ if eq(parameters.test, 'true') }}:
      value: false
  ${{ elseif eq(parameters.test, 'false') }}:
      value: true

stages:
- template: job-templates/template.yml
  parameters:
    testrue: $(test-true)
```

**template.yml**

```
parameters:
  testrue: test_true
  
stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
    - job: JA
      steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Reverted value is" ${{ parameters.testrue }}
          
        name: DetermineResult
```

How can I move the if else logic in the template.yml instead of azure-caller.yml? Your input will be helpful. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below pipeline should do the trick with a limitation that the scope of variable test-true in the template will be limited only for stage: A

**azure-caller.yml**

```
parameters:
  - name: test
    displayName: 'select true or false' 
    values:
      - true
      - false

stages:
- template: job-templates/template.yml
  parameters:
    testrue: ${{ parameters.test }}
```

**template.yml**

```
parameters:
  testrue: default

stages:
  - stage: A
    variables:
    - name: test-true
      ${{ if eq(parameters.testrue, 'true') }}:
        value: NewValueForTrueParam
      ${{ elseif eq(parameters.testrue, 'false') }}:
        value: NewValueForFalseParam
    jobs:
    - job: JA
      steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Echo value is" $(test-true)
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Azure -caller.yml works fine, its the problem with template.yml, i want to move the if else logic inside template.yml, how can i do that?

Comment: Why do you need if else logic? When you can just pass true and false directly as a parameter.

Comment: ok, use case is a little different than in the example above, I am doing, some configuration and I dont want to give access to the user to be able to edit the template.yml whereas they can play around with wrapper, i.e. azure-caller.yml

Comment: i have updated the question, i.e. reverted logic, but it doesnt matter as its not the exact use case i am doing rather an example, all i am trying to understand is how to be able to use if else logic inside a parameter, so i can do configurations to the parameters passed through the caller pipeline (i.e. azure-pipeline.yml"

Comment: updated the solution :)

Comment: Can you please retest once, it is working for me. I have updated the solution again with my result screenshot.

Comment: your pipeline as it is working, let me check with my original intended use-case logic. I tried this exact thing earlier it failed on me, let me see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241006/discussion-between-tejas-nagchandi-and-lavoizer).

Comment: This works man!

Comment: @ Tejas Nagchandi - I am having some issues, I am trying to select service connection with this if else logic, however, I am getting errors, do you know how can I select service connection at runtime?