# Azure DevOps Pipeline Dynamically List Members of Variable Group

Tags: yaml, cypress, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm trying to have a YAML pipeline build out a JSON file to be used as a `Cypress.env.json`. Some of the values need to come from a variable group (ultimately tied to an Azure Key Vault). I want it to be build dynamically so if a secret is added to the Key Vault and exposed via the Variable Group it will be written out as a new property of the JSON file without the YAML pipeline needing to be modified. I was hopeful I had found a trick in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66976823/123147) which describes an undocumented function named `convertToJson` which allows a pipeline object to be passed as a JSON string to a script. So I gave this a try:

```yaml
- job:
  variables:
  - group: DevVariableGroup
  steps:
  - bash: echo "${{ convertToJson(variables) }}"
    displayName: 'Get an Object - Bash'
```

This works insofar as I get a JSON string with all variables which are available at compile time. Unfortunately, the variables provided by the variable group are not among them. I've only been able to get the `convertToJson` function to work using the template syntax, not macro or runtime syntax.

I can't think of another way to dynamically access the variables provided by the variable group. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would circle back to this question and share the solution we landed on in case it's helpful for anyone else. The secrets are held in a Key Vault and retrieved using the [AzureKeyVault@1 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops). That downloads the values to variables, so there isn't a need to rely on a Variable Group to expose the Key Vault's contents. Once they are variables, we can use the [replacetokens@3 task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens). So we changed the JSON file into which we are populating the values so it would work with that task.

Two tasks got us what we needed.

```yaml
  - task: AzureKeyVault@1
    displayName: 'Read vault'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
      KeyVaultName: $(keyVaultName)
      SecretsFilter: '*'
      RunAsPreJob: false

  - task: replacetokens@3
    inputs:
      targetFiles: '**/cypress.json'
      encoding: 'auto'
      writeBOM: true
      actionOnMissing: 'warn'
      keepToken: false
      tokenPrefix: '#{'
      tokenSuffix: '}#'
      useLegacyPattern: false
      enableTransforms: false
      enableTelemetry: true
```